# Why Oracle need a Select Into for a normal Query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following simple code:

```
 declare
 var number;

 Begin
   var := 1;
   select * from Table where Table_ID = :var;
 end;
```

Executing that, I receive the error

> an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

If I instead just type it...

```
select * from Table where Table_ID = 1;
```

...it works!

Where does that error come from? Why do I need an `Into` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a "normal" query.  This is a query in a PL/SQL code block.  And, such a block does not know how to output results.

When you specify the `INTO` clause, then PL/SQL does know what to do with the results -- put them into variables.

Comment: Thanks i come from T-SQL and it was not needed. "Select into " is use for another things.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle got 2 types of engines. 1) SQL engine and 2) PLSQL engine. 
When you simply type

```
select * from Table where Table_ID = 1;
```

SQL engines plays here and fetch the output. And you see no issues here.

When you run the anonymous block:

```
 declare
 var number;

 Begin

   var := 1;
   select * from Test where A = :var;
 end;
```

The fetch operation takes place in 2 steps. First PLSQL engine checks the syntax of the your command,resolve the variable declared in program and then pass on the control to SQL engine. This phenomena is called Context switching. There is no provision in PLSQL to directly display the resultset obtained from the SQL engine. Hence you get the issue. 
Once you declare the variable, the SQL engine binds the resultset to variables declared and you can display the results using dbs_ouput.put_line pacakage.